# Show specific div on page refresh

Tags: html

I have a page with four tabs displayed on the basis of their `id` . I have a `form` in second tab and on its submission i need the page to go to third tab . But it refresh and go back to first tab . I tried to give the `div` `id` in `url` but it wont work

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understood your question completely

BUT

This might Temporary solve your doubt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#your3rdDivId').show();
})
```

You require `jQuery` for the above solution

Comment: Also you'll want to let them know that you're using jQuery. I think their question was about `meta-refresh`

Comment: Yeah, they could also fire it with an `onsubmit()` from the form itself and handle the form via AJAX, but that's a lot more work. :)